# What should be done with posts by removed users if the posts or the associated comments contain useful information?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

The example that motivated this question is [this answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/22494/7590) on [this question](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/22491/7590) (since not everyone can view the answer, I believe). The answer raised a point that led to a discussion in the comments, which contained points not addressed in any of the other answers.

For the sake of preservation, should answers/comment threads like this that provide useful information

1. be undeleted in their current form, so others can see them
2. edited into a separate answer, possibly a [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/218097) answer. I just learned about the wiki feature, so that seems like an option.
3. remain deleted per the user's request

or some other option?

Obviously in *this* case, I could edit the information from the comments into my answer because I'm the one who posted much of it, but I'm asking about in general if this occurs again. Furthermore, I'm likely biased towards the information in this post and its comments because I contributed the discussion; the information may *not* be useful for the question at all and may merit no action, which is why I present the question in general.

I noticed that this user deleted *a lot* of his answers long before leaving the site, so the issue may be present in other questions as well.

Answer (score 4):

I think we can un-delete if you feel like it adds something to the site.  A couple of up-votes (and a comment so I know about them) and I will do that for you no problem.

In future circumstances like this, I think they just have to be un deleted by committee like everything else.

You could also use it to generate some more points for yourself if the questions / answer are good enough to bring back. (I don't know how the discussion you linked would do that, but you are smart enough to try.)

Comment: In the example discussion, I would probably edit the information I presented into my answer. In the majority of cases (I assume, since I've only been involved in this one example) the information presented in a deleted answer *isn't* mine, in which case it seems disingenuous to earn points for it by posting a new answer without the wiki enabled. If an answer like that generates enough criticism, indicating my judgement *wasn't* correct, I can always remove it. Perhaps I'm overthinking this.

Comment: @JohnBensin If somebody deleted their profile and their answer is lost, I say it's **fair game** to re-post a similar answer .. but put your own spin on it, e.g. add some value, more supporting references, if it wasn't the best of answers to begin with.